# Serving media files on S3 for saleor

Tags: django, amazon-s3, saleor

I have used saleor,django store and hosted it on google cloud, It is working fine. Now what I wanted to do is to host media files on S3 bucket. I have created a bucket and tried some tutorials but no success. I could not find any complete step by step guide for this. If anyone can help me with this problem it will be helpful.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('accessid')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('accesskey')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('testbucket')
```

I followed this guide for saleor S3 integration: https://saleor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment/s3.html

Now here is the situation I have created the bucket and have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`,`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` 
Can someone guide me from here how to serve media files on S3 for saleor

Answer (score 1):

The Saleor documentation is good but a little sparse.  I had more luck following these instructions (read the installation section and then the S3 one -- this is the library Saleor is using anyways):

https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I would start by configuring your local-running- app to use S3 for its static files and run `python manage.py collectstatic` for a tighter debugging loop.

Comment: I followed their documentation and also asked them, but the issue seems to be with
`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('accessid')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('accesskey')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('testbucket'`
its not picking up the vaules.

Comment: Are you actually setting those values in the environment? Usually they'd be all caps.  Like mine in heroku are called "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" not "accessid"

Comment: is it safe to directly set them like this `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=myaccesskey`?

Answer (score 0):

After creating the bucket you have to update your `media/static urls` and also add your aws keys(I recommend adding them through env variable).

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('accessid') 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('accesskey') 
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('testbucket'
```

Once done now you need to setup the configuration of your bucket and thats it.